# Why there is a never ending line (text does not place to next line when it exceeds its container's div width)

Tags: html, css

I can't get rid of this. I am using a wrapper to wrap content in a fixed width `div`. Here is [my site](http://go.theshashwat.com). If length of text is too high then remaining text is not displaying in the next line as it should usually.

I am just novice in `CSS`. I have used `overflow:hidden` in header `div` just to remove some extra margin that could not be removed using `margin: 0`. I tried removing `overflow` property if it has anything to do but no luck.

I am using `ddsmoothmenu` from dynamic drive. I have also tried removing this but still nothing good.

#### Added Later

**Another issue** here is that If I zoom too much so that browser window falls shorter than width of the wrapper and scrolling horizontally seems like width of wrapper is decreasing too. Same behavior I do see in [nuget](http://nuget.org).

Here is some of the CSS I have writted:

```
body {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    margin:0 0;
    font-family:'Segoe UI';
}

.wrapper, #main-menu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#page {
    background-color:white;
}

#main {
    min-height:200px;
}
#header {
    height: 80px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #80b8dd;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #80b8dd 0%, #188edd 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#80b8dd), color-stop(100%,#188edd));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #80b8dd 0%,#188edd 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #80b8dd 0%,#188edd 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #80b8dd 0%,#188edd 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #80b8dd 0%,#188edd 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#80b8dd', endColorstr='#188edd',GradientType=0 );
}

#navigation {
    height:37px;
    background-color:#414141;
}

#logo {
    margin:10px 0 10px 10px;
}
```

Please help !!!

Comment: Can you please try with some spaces in your text.

Comment: @JoeSpurling how could I miss this point..
But another issue here is that If I zoom too much so that browser window falls shorter than width of the wrapper and scrolling horizontally seems like width of wrapper is decreasing too. Same behavior I do see in [nuget](http://nuget.org).

Comment: Not related to the issue itself, but your page appears to be missing the copyright notice for the script.

Comment: @Bernie copyright ..?? I hv just started development of this site and designing its layout. Why do I need copyright now ..?

Comment: @harsh, it's a requirement for using the script on a live site. Why did you remove it in the first place?

Comment: which script ..?? `ddsmoothmenu` ..?? @Bernie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no spaces in your text. Use lorem ipsum for testing. Here are some generators:

- http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/
- http://hipsteripsum.me/ (hipster ipsum)
- http://cupcakeipsum.com/ (cupcake ipsum if you want something
  a little sweeter)

You can use CSS `word-break` property for breaking words in situations where you do have to deal with [gigantic words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lopado%C2%ADtemacho%C2%ADselacho%C2%ADgaleo%C2%ADkranio%C2%ADleipsano%C2%ADdrim%C2%ADhypo%C2%ADtrimmato%C2%ADsilphio%C2%ADparao%C2%ADmelito%C2%ADkatakechy%C2%ADmeno%C2%ADkichl%C2%ADepi%C2%ADkossypho%C2%ADphatto%C2%ADperister%C2%ADalektryon%C2%ADopte%C2%ADkephallio%C2%ADkigklo%C2%ADpeleio%C2%ADlagoio%C2%ADsiraio%C2%ADbaphe%C2%ADtragano%C2%ADpterygon):

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Alternative if you only want to break words at appropriate hyphantion points:

```
word-break: hyphenate;
```

Comment: +1 ohh.. how could I miss this point..
But another issue here is that If I zoom too much so that browser window falls shorter than width of the wrapper and scrolling horizontally seems like width of wrapper is decreasing too. Same behavior I do see in [nuget](http://nuget.org).

Comment: @harsh The link to your site is down now so I can't see this new problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#page {
    background-color: #fff;
    word-break: break-all;
}

#main {
    min-height: 200px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```